# Bootstrap alert JS won't slide down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using this JS:

```
 $('#comment').click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $('#comment').slideDown();
                        });
                }
```

And this html code:

```
<div id="comment" class="alert alert-info" style="margin-top: 20px; display: none;"></div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="route_update">Edit</button>
```

it should, if successful, slide down with the message...But it don't, the blue bar won't go down.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('#route_update').click(function() {
    $('#comment').slideDown();
});
```

**Explanation:**

Your jQuery requires the hidden element to be clicked in order to show the alert. This won't work.

Using the 'Edit' button's ID to call the function works.

Comment: I removed the `e.preventDefault();` to keep my answer simple, and for no other reason.

Comment: @Thauawa it doens't work. 
Check the complete code here: http://pastebin.com/9kPMqgSb

Comment: Can you add your HTML too?